# (PHP) Returning picture from a directory

Tags: php

In my Product Class, there is a function called pictures() which returns the file address of the picture of a product. It's something like this:

```
public function picture()
{
    $file = "images/pictures/products/" . $this->id . ".png";
    if(file_exists($file))
        return $file;
    else
        return false;
}
```

It works fine when running the code on the administration area of the website (which is located on /admin/ directory)

But when I call this function from the index.php which is not on the /admin/ directory it always returns false. What should I do? The only way I figured to solve this is by creating a parameter on the picture() function, like: picture($directory_prefix) then that way I'll call the function with picture("/admin/"). But there's gotta be a better way than this...

Answer (score 2):

Place your resources in a directory under the web root. Then the path would be:

```
$file = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/images/pictures/products/" . $this->id . ".png";
```